# Conectar thymeleaf con una lista de objetos

Tags: java, json, mvc, spring, thymeleaf

Actualmente estoy utilizando estas tecnologias

1. SPRING MVC
2. HIBERNATE
3. JPA
4. THYMELEAF
5. JACKSON JSON

cree un formulario donde envio un objeto de tipo receta

```
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Id
private int id;
private String nombre;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "receta_ingredientes", nullable = false)
private Receta receta_ingredientes;
```

y esta clase tiene 2 listas de clases (Ingredientes y Pasos ) al momento de generar el formulario pues lo hago de esta manera

donde pido que separen por comas ( para separarlos en el controlador y hacer una lista de cada cosa ) desgraciadamente no se puede

asi que estoy buscando la manera de que thymeleaf automaticamente cree una lista de una clase al ver que el input tiene una coma

algo asi estan mis inputs :

//Ingredientes

```
<input class="form-control" th:field="*{ingredients}" type="text" placeholder="Ingredientes">
```

//Pasos

```
<input class="form-control" th:field="*{pasos}" type="text" placeholder="Ingredientes">
```

alguna idea de como conectar esto ( que al momento de que thymeleaf vea una coma cree otro objeto para solo generar una lista de objetos )

Comment: Es bastante trabajo. Pero no me queda muy claro. Quieres que agregar pasos de manera dinamica  he ingredientes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas crear una clase que contenga una lista `List<String> pasos` y con `List<String> ingredientes`.

Dentro de thymeleaf iteras sobre ellos con un `for:each="${ingrediente, i:ingredientes}`

Los inputs los tienes que generar con `post` de manera que con alguna funcion `js` cada vez que presiones `","` envíes el formulario con los datos (o amenos que pongas una variable de seción si no me equivoco) y agregues en un controller un nuevo objeto a tu lista que pasas como parámetro.

Despues muestras cada elemento así (Suponiendo que lo hagas en un input aparte y solo por poner un ejemplo de acceso a los datos dentro de una lista):

```
<input type="text" th:field="${ingrediente[i.index]}"/ >
```

Nótese que el elemento `i.index` enumera los valores en la lista para que thymeleaf sepa qué objeto estas modificando. Sin esto el controller no recivira los cambios.

> El código está directo. Puede contener errores.

Comment: si hace tiempo lo corregi xD !! asi justamente cree un modelo simple ahora si que un simple VO o DTO para hacerlo mas rapido

Comment: Excelente! Spring es un dolor de cabeza al principio pero despues es un sueño echo realidad :D